# Using standard library only, how to wrap error in custom error?

Tags: go, error-handling

Since Go 1.13 we have the ability to chain errors, unwrap them and check if any error in the chain matches any of expected errors via `errors.Is()` and `errors.As()`.

To wrap an error all you have to do is use `%w` verb with `fmt.Errorf()` like below.

```
fmt.Errorf("Custom message: %w", err)
```

This is easy, it wraps `err` in another one with additional message. But let's say I need some more context than just a message. How do I wrap `err` in my own, structured, custom error? Using Go 1.13+ standard library only.

Answer (score 11):

You may create a new error type which wraps other errors while providing additional structured information.

```golang
type MyError struct {
    Inner error
    // Provide any additional fields that you need.
    Message string
    AdditionalContext string 
}

// Error is mark the struct as an error.
func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("error caused due to %v; message: %v; additional context: %v", e.Inner, e.Message, e.AdditionalContext)
}

// Unwrap is used to make it work with errors.Is, errors.As.
func (e *MyError) Unwrap() error {
    // Return the inner error.
    return e.Inner
}

// WrapWithMyError to easily create a new error which wraps the given error.
func WrapWithMyError(err error, message string, additionalContext string) error {
    return &MyError {
        Inner: err,
        Message: message,
        AdditionalContext: additionalContext,
    }
}
```

You need to implement `Error` and `Unwrap` interfaces to use the new features of `errors.Is` and `errors.As`.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I wanted. Additionally I've checked std lib fmt.Errorf code and it does exactly this. It creates a struct with inner error and Unwrap method. I wish Unwrap method was part of an interface, but it seems it isn't.

Comment: Unwrap is part of an ad-hoc interface at https://golang.org/src/errors/wrap.go?s=372:400#L4.

Comment: I meant classical, exposed interface. Turns our there is no specific reason for that - they couldn't come up with a name. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35306

Answer (score -1):

Errors are an interface (satisfied by `error() string`) So you can make another error type as:

```
type myCustomError struct {
  Message    string
  StatusCode int
}

func (m myCustomError) error() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("Code %d: \tMessage: %s", m.StatusCode, m.Message) 
}
```

Now you can use an error that is thrown as a custom error with

```
_, err := doStuff()
var v myCustomError
if errors.As(err, &v) {
   // now v is parsed 
}
```

Comment: Question was not about creating customer error but wrapping existing error in the custom one to create an error chain, which can be later checked with errors.As and errors.Is functions.